# Backbone Marionette : Reusable UI Elements

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm building my first Backbone Marionette application, but I'm confused how to add reusable UI to my view templates, where those UI elements have JavaScript interaction.

I have built a number of UI elements like the input element shown below. This input element can be interacted with via JavaScript, for example by clicking the up/down arrows to change the input's value.

[image: UI Element]

These UI elements should be reused again and again in multiple views, and there can be many instances of these UI elements contained within any given view. A mockup for one such view, containing several UI elements, is shown below.

[image: Group of UI Elements]

A model for this view might look like this, and I would like to have the JavaScript interaction of my UI elements interacting with this view's model. In other words, the JavaScript interaction on a UI element will have to be able to pass an event to the model of the view inside which the UI element is shown.

```
var fontStyles = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        fontFamily: "Helvetica Neue",
        fontWeight: "Regular",
        color: "rbg(1,197,255)"
        ...
    }
});
```

---

**My Question**

For a properly structured Backbone Marionette application, where would I define these reusable UI elements and their JavaScript interaction methods, in such a way that I can reuse them throughout all of my views/modules?

As another concern, will it be possible to write the HTML for these UI elements once, in a template file, and then reuse that single UI template file again and again in the underscore templates of my views? Or will I have to repeat the HTML for my UI elements in the template of every view?

Thank you for any help, and if my question is unclear please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create this elements as Marionette.ItemView's extensions
Each item view should be created and placed into region inside layout you want to use them
And of course, since it is ItemView it contains template:some_template, 
Or Marionette.Layout extensions if they by itself also contain regions

So, as for your pictures
Small picture is ItemView
Big picture is Layout, which contains number of regions, each region contain widget, which is ItemView.

Layout receives model:some_model on initialization (Layout is extension of ItemView)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tigra. I've found that another option is simply to write my UI interactions in a single file and shim that in my RequireJS definition. Then, in my Backbone views, I just listen for value change events on the input fields rather than listening for JavaScript interactions.